# How to update url to new, but save old in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem, i need to update url to new, but if user get old address need redirect to new. The main problem that at me the abstract state. 
Example route:

```
{
    name: 'process',
    config: {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
    }
},
{
    name: 'process.one',
    config: {
        url: '/process/:process_name',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
        controller: 'OneProcess',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
},
{
    name: 'process.one.space',
    config: {
        url: '/version/:mode',
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/process-space.html',
        controller: 'ProcessSpace',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
},
{
    name: 'process.one.analytics',
    config: {
        url: '/analytics',
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/analytics.html',
        controller: 'AnalyticsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
},
```

Needed replace `url: '/process/:process_name'` to `url: '/processes/:process_name'` What best way to make it?

Comment: Is this a question about `angular` or `angularjs`?

Comment: @Yoav `angularjs`